# MVVM WPF ComboBox SelectedValue isn't the exact value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I'm trying to implement a combobox in a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Here is the combobox :

```
<ComboBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Width="300"
    BorderThickness="1"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextForeground}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Categories, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Category, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Categories is an IEnumerable list of Category:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Category is a property from the Transaction list who is also the itemssource of my Datagrid :

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Transaction> _transactions;
public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions => _transactions;
```

The problem is when I open the row of my datagrid the combobox does not take the value of selectedValue Category but she just take the first item of the itemssource Categories
Also when I select a value from the combobox the same value is selected for all the line in the datagrid.

Comment: I suspect your collection `Categories` has a different object but the same properties as what's in the `Transaction` class.  ComboBox is comparing instances if that is the case.  Consider using `SelectedValuePath` with `SelectedValue`.

Comment: Oh i get it thanks, this resolve the first problem, but now when i choose something on one combobox all the combobox take the same value do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd modify as the following, considering your list of categories is `Categories`, you previously set in your ViewModel `SelectedCategory`, and your class Category has an attribute `Name`.

```
<ComboBox 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategory}"
  //Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged not necessary
  DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5"
/>
```